# Round to max N decimals

Tags: c++, rounding

I know how to print a rounded number to N decimals like this:

```
using namespace std;

cout << setprecision(N) << fixed;
float k = 1.23441;
cout << k;
```

Let's use for example N = 2.

This will output 1.23, which is good, but if k is 1.0012, it will output 1.00, and I want it to output 1. If k is 1.1045, it will output 1.10, and I want it to output 1.1, so I want to round to 2 decimals and remove the unnecesary zeroes.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the problem is not `setprecision`, it's `fixed`. With `fixed` you *explicitly asked* to have a fixed number of digits!

If you use `setprecision` without `fixed`, it'll do exactly what you are asking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double const number = 123.456789;
    for (int i = 0; i != 15; ++i) { std::cout << i << ": " << std::setprecision(i) << number << "\n"; }
    return 0;
}
```

Will [output](http://ideone.com/eA08DI):

```
0: 1e+02
1: 1e+02
2: 1.2e+02
3: 123
4: 123.5
5: 123.46
6: 123.457
7: 123.4568
8: 123.45679
9: 123.456789
10: 123.456789
11: 123.456789
12: 123.456789
13: 123.456789
14: 123.456789
```

You can find documentation on the different modes [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

- `fixed`
- `scientific`
- `hexfloat`
- `defaultfloat`

And what you want is `defaultfloat`, which as the name implies is the default.

Comment: This is good C++ tutoring, but does not solve OP's problem. ;-) Neither `fixed` nor `setprecision` cause the omission of trailing zeros in a fraction.

Comment: @laune: actually, as far as I can see, this is exactly what the OP is asking for: rounding to max N significant digits, eliding the trailing 0s, is achieved by using `setprecision(N)` and `defaultfloat`.

Comment: Indeed, I should have checked.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of (seemingly) redundant zeros at the end should not be suppressed. Consider

```
1.2
1.23
1.234
1.2000
1.2300
1.2340
```

The first number says that it is 1.2 +/- 0.05, the next one says it's 1.23 +/- 0.005 and the third one, 1.234 +/- 0.0005.

In constrast, all of the following numbers indicate a precision that isn't farther off than 0.00005.

So, removing trailing zeros in a decimal fraction is not a way to present date more readable; usually the lack of trailing digits is understood to indicate a lack of precision in the computation.

**Later**

The removal of characters from a string resulting from a formatted conversion must be coded explicitly if the conversion does not meet your requirements. Therefore, convert to a string using the format that's closest to your requirements, and then post-process the string.

If the string is the result of some fixed-point formatted conversion, according to the pattern `\d+\.\d+`, you can reverse-scan the string from the end (hint: `string::find_last_not_of`). Do you want to truncate `1.000` to `1.0` or `1.` or `1`? The last form will even insinuate that the value is an integer, which it isn't.

Comment: This is a valuable comment, but hardly an answer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Be that as it may be, but I've tried to alert OP to the dangers of dropping trailing zeros in a fraction.

Comment: @landisme I can always extend or retract my answer. Sometimes, the formatting capabilities of a command aren't satisfactory.